# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest when loading charts.js in to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

Currently I have a menu down the left hand side of the page and when you click the navigation it loads the page using the following:

```
if (this.id == "view-charts") {
    $("#rightContainer").load("view-charts.php");
    $(this).addClass("current");
}
```

This is working fine for every page, except for this current page with charts.js whenever this page is loaded I get the following error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. jquery.min.js:6

Furthermore, if I simply php include the page in to the parent page, it gives out the same error.

Comment: You've set `async: false` somewhere in your code, possibly in `$.ajaxStart()`. You need to remove it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have not used async, furthermore, even if there is no ajax code and I simply PHP include the code, it gives this error.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not including any JS files by default in your template? The only way you'll see this error is when you send a synchronous AJAX request. It's possible it's part of a library you're using. If so you should find an alternative as sync requests are incredibly bad practice

Comment: I've taken out every other script and js file. All that's left are the jquery library and the links to the charts.js files.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Could it be to do with the content on the charts page? It uses the following `window.onload = function() {` however the window is already loaded and the content is being loaded in to a new div rather than the window being reloaded?

Comment: No - that's the `load` event handler and nothing to do with AJAX. I can't help you without seeing your code. All I'd suggest you do is remove things one at a time, line by line until the error disappears

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this warning, do not use:

async: false
in any of your $.ajax() calls. This is the only feature of XMLHttpRequest that's deprecated.

The default is async: true, so if you never use this option at all, your code should be safe if the feature is ever really removed (it probably won't be -- it may be removed from the standards, but I'll bet browsers will continue to support it for many years).

Comment: I have not used it, furthermore, even if there is no ajax code and I simply PHP include the code, it gives this error.